# Fare calculator for travel in greater Lisbon?

Tags: public-transport, portugal, fares, lisbon

TL;DR: **Is there an easy way to get detailed fare calculations for the Lisbon area?**

On my last day in Lisbon I'm looking to visit Sintra.  I gather day passes aren't going to cut it, so I need to preload my *Viva Viagem* with enough delightfully named "Zapping" credit that will get me from my hotel to Rossio by Metro, from Rossio to Sintra by CP train, and cover the 434 bus in Sintra.

However, I'm totally unable to locate a fare calculator that can tell me how much this will cost all together, so I can load *just* enough credit -- because there's no way to refund leftovers.  Any pointers?  Neither Rome2Rio nor Google Maps cut the mustard, and trying to piece together the individual fares across 3 systems while accounting for the Viva Viagem discounts etc is rather nightmarish.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think Zapping is compatible on 434. Then you just need to add metro + CP train to sintra.

Comment: @xngtng Ooh, looks like you're correct, thanks for pointing that out!